# Is there a directive which allows a select element to be hidden once an option has been selected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a directive which allows a select element to be hidden once an 
option has been selected?

I thought `ng-blur` was the way to go but it's not working for me.

```
select(ng-model="jawn", ng-options="range.value for range in ranges", 
ng-blur="hideMe", ng-if="jawnDropdown")

$scope.hideMe = function() {
    $scope.jawnDropdown = false;
}
```

Comment: Use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` to check if a particular condition is true/false, then hide/show accordingly.

Comment: I'm using `ng-if` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you pivot off the model?

```
select(ng-model="jawn", ng-options="range.value for range in ranges", ng-if="!jawn")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show or ng-hide by binding it with the same model of the select box in this way :

```
<select ng-model="modelName" ng-show="modelName == '' || modelName == null" ng-change="functionName(modelName)">
    <option value="">Select name</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="item.id">{{item.name}}</select>
</select>
```

This will show the select box only if the **modelName**'s value is null or empty & when you select something the condition in ng-show returns false & the select box will hide & you can use the ng-change directive to do any other operation on the select box's value.

Hope this helps
Cheers